# How to use the OR modifier with excluded terms in a phrase in a Craigslist search

Tags: search, craigslist

How do you reformulate the following craigslist search to avoid repeating the word "no" twice (in order to comply with a word limit in searches).

```
-"no pets" -"no dogs"
```

I have tried the following:

```
-(no "pets | dogs")
-"no (pets | dogs)"
-"no pets | dogs"
```

Comment: A) Why do you want to do this search? B) What do you mean about a word limit? Please [edit] your original post and enlighten us.

Comment: C) It looks like Craigslist searches are probably handled by Sphinx search (though I may be wrong). Don't just look at Craigslist's [search help page](https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/search): also look at [chapter 5 of the Sphinx search manual](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#searching) as well. You can read it online, for free. It's much more detailed than Craigslist's search help page. I haven't read it all, so I don't know whether or not it answers your question. But you should read it. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You technically want place that do allow pets/dogs correct? I assume thats why you want to exclude the phrases that inlclude no in it? try this one:

```
-"no pets|dogs"
```

Comment: craigslist does not use the + operator: https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/search

Comment: I tried the search and it yielded the apparent results requested

Comment: It yields *some* results, but the number of results is much smaller than if you just search for the original phrase, so it's not doing something right.

Comment: -"no pets|dog"  works just fine, you can tell if you try the search  without the minus sign and look into the results to see if the phrase you want to exclude actually is in the posting - if yours didnt work before - might have something to do with the extra spaces you left between the words and the pipe character

Comment: As I said, *-"no pets" -"no dogs"* and *-"no pets|dogs"* (the space doesn't matter) return different numbers of results.  You're probably not testing it in a large enough sample.  Try the apartments section of a large city.

Comment: ok dude. if San Francisco, where I live, if that apartments sample isnt large enough to test on then your SOL. Good luck. Why don't you just check the default box for "dogs ok".

Comment: I already told you that I tested your suggestion and the numbers *don't* match, which means your string is not the exact replacement as far as craigslist is concerned.  If you are going to be pissy when your answers turn out to be wrong, then this is not the site for you.  And there is a simple and logical reason why checking off "dogs ok" is NOT the same as excluding listings where dogs are specifically not OK, but if you can't figure it out, then you should work on your own logic before helping others.

Comment: the reason, is that your question clearly states that your doing it to comply with a word limit on searches - perhaps your other parameters are preventing you from getting what you need. I guarantee you that even putting the two string separate as you said you did in your first example, is not exceeding the limit.

Comment: The other parameters are not interfering.  I tested it again without other parameters, and no, your string is not a replacement for the original string. **It returns a different number of results.**  There is no better test than this.  I really can't see how else I can explain this to you.  Your string is doing something other than what you think it's doing.  It's possible that there is no answer to this question because of craigslist's limitations.  But you really need to stop pushing the *wrong* answer--it does not check out.

Comment: For crying out loud, I just tested it with San Francisco just to put the entire nail in the coffin, and as expected, it returns different results there too.  Computer programs don't work differently depending on locale.  It is disrespectful of other people's time to provide answers without thoroughly testing them first.